# how to replace dash to space in directory

Tags: php, directory

I have a Folder which name is

Apple-photos

and i want to replace - to space so how can i do this 
this code is showing directory name like this
Apple-photos and i want like this Apple photos

```
<?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME));?>
```

i have one more code to replace - to space but how can i merge it in my code
here is replace code

```
<?php echo ''.ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$title)).'';?>
```

i am not expert in php please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

complete code

```
<?php

    //path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a subdirectory
    $directory = "albums/*/";

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_DESC, $images);

?>

<?php $num_of_files = 0; $i=0; foreach ($images as $image):?>
<div class="item"><a href="<?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)); ?>.html" target="_blank">
<img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
<p><?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)); ?></p>
             </div>
<?php if (++$num_of_files == 3)break; ?>
  <?php if(++$i%3==0): ?>

<?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic way of doing it.

```
$old = "Apple-Photos";
$new = str_replace("-", " ", $old);

rename($old, $new);
```

If you need to grab the directory of a file, and then rename that. 
It will need additional code to strip out the exact directory from the path name and so on.

Comment: how to fix your code in to my code <?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME));?>

Comment: What is the value of $image